Definition of conjugation of complex Grassmannian numbers
In Peskin and Schroeder QFT page 300 it is said that the complex conjugation of a Grassmannian number is defined to reverse the order of products:
$$ (\theta \eta)^* =  \eta^* \theta^* \tag{9.65}$$
Although this definition seems to contradict the following calculation:
$$ (\theta \eta)^* = ( (\theta_1 + i\theta_2) (\eta_1 + i\eta_2))^* = ((\theta_1\eta_1 - \theta_2\eta_2) + i(\theta_2\eta_1 + \theta_1\eta_2))^* = (\theta_1\eta_1 - \theta_2\eta_2) - i(\theta_2\eta_1 + \theta_1\eta_2)$$
$$  \eta^* \theta^* = (\eta_1 + i\eta_2)^*(\theta_1 + i\theta_2)^*  = (\eta_1 - i\eta_2)(\theta_1 - i\theta_2) = (\eta_1\theta_1 - \eta_2\theta_2) - i(\eta_1\theta_2 + \eta_2\theta_1)$$
where $\theta_i$ and $\eta_i$ are real Grassmannian numbers and $\theta = \theta_1 + i\theta_2$ and $\eta= \eta_1 + i\eta_2$.
Thus $$ (\theta \eta)^* = -\eta^* \theta^* $$ contradicting the definition.
Can someone explain to me what I didn't understand correctly?

Hint: Eq. (9.65) does also apply to real Grassmann numbers.

@Qmechanic Ok thanks I understood.

The mistake in your calculation is to assume that the product of two real Grassmann numbers is still real. This is not true due to to 9.65. Consider two real Grassmann numbers:
$$
\theta^* = \theta\quad \eta^* = \eta \\
(\theta\eta)^* = \eta^*\theta^* = \eta\theta = -\theta\eta
$$
so their product $\theta\eta$ is purely imaginary. Therefore, for the last step of your first evaluation of $(\theta\eta)^*$, you are off by a minus sign. Accounting for this, the results are now consistent.

Thanks for your answer! But how would you define the complex conjunction of a single Grassmannian number?
